# C++ Filie i/o read two ints at once

Tags: c++, file, io

I have a text file with numbers in pairs in the form

```
1 5 6 8 9 7
```

or

```
3 4
```

All the files have a even number of numbers.
How can I get allways the next two ints instead of just one?

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(...);
int n;
while (inFile >> n) {
    int m;
    inFile >> m;
    pb.import(n, m);
}
```

This gives a type error for m.

pb.import requires two ints.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just read two ints at a time:

```
int n, m;
while (inFile >> n >> m) {
    pb.import(n, m);
}
```